# Как использовать оператор IN в pdo, если нужно чтобы фильтрация была по нескольким строчным элементам?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Пытаюсь реализовать фильтр товаров на сайте, но в операторе IN получается занести лишь один параметр, если в массиве $_POST будет 2 и более ключей, то результат пуст.
Код представлен ниже:

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM product WHERE price != 0
";

 if(isset($_POST["type"]))
 {
  $type_filter = implode(",", $_POST["type"]);
  $query .= "
   AND type IN(:type)
  ";
 }
 if(isset($_POST["activation"]))
 {
  $activation_filter = implode(",", $_POST["activation"]);
  $query .= "
   AND activation IN(:activation)
  ";
 }

if(isset($_POST["type"]))
{
$statement->bindParam(":type", $type_filter);
}

if(isset($_POST["activation"]))
{
$statement->bindParam(":activation", $activation_filter);
}

$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Так же пробовал преобразовывать массив в строку и таким способом, чтобы элементы были в одинарной кавычке:

```
$type_filter = implode("','", $_POST["type"]);
  $query .= "
   AND type IN(':type')
  ";
```

Результат тот же.

Comment: `AND type IN(:type1, :type2, :type3, :type4)`

Comment: 1) А какие значения находятся в _POST? Можешь показать? 2) Я не вижу, чтобы ты подготавливал запрос, типа `$statement->prepare($query);`

Comment: 3) Чтобы сделать то что ты хочешь, типа "как сделать запрос если в $_POST много разных данных". Не делать же много ифов. Поэтому тебе нужно использовать такие функции, как: `array_values()` и `array_keys()`. С помощью `array_keys`  достаешь имена ключей из массива, создаешь цикл по этим ключам, и соединяешь их в строку запроса и вроде вместо IN можно = ставить, и после = ставишь `?`. А значения этих ключей пропускаешь через цикл, а в цикле bindParam и значение. Думаю ты понял

Comment: @Евгений Хорошо, спасибо, попробую.